# Working with Regex to get 2 strings out of a source code

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

Ive just asked this question but forgot to add some information that brings this to another aspect.

I am trying to get 2 strings out of a source page code, the 2 strings are in this line:

```
<td style="cursor:pointer;" class="" onclick="NewWindow('U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..', 'bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1', 'bpvstage_edit', '1200', '800')" onmouseout="HideHover();"><img src="gfx/info.gif" alt="" tipwidth="450" ajaxtip="openajax.php?target=modules/bpv/bpvstage_hover_info.php&rid=2567&oid=3511&bpvsid=921434&bpvname=test%bv" /></td>
```

The 2 strings I am trying to obtian:

```
U_nQgAjU_tdUnfcA7lT5opoTLyLdslWDTpiNzcdkLoHlobS_HbujMw..
```

And

```
bpvsid=nvnN2JFJqJc.&dcz=1
```

However since I am searching trough a WHOLE source page I cannot simple split on onclick="NewWindow(', because there are 20 other search result if you search for this.

I found out that: `class="" onclick="NewWindow('` is unique (Code before the long code).

I got some very good replies that would work if this string would be the only text in the source code, example:

```
var match = Regex.Match(reader.ReadToEnd(), @"onclick=""NewWindow\('([^']*)',\s*'([^']*)',.*");
if (match.Success)
{
    string longId = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string other = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

However when I try to change: `reader.ReadToEnd(), @"onclick=""NewWindow\('([^']*)',\s*'([^']*)',.*");`

To

`reader.ReadToEnd(), @"class="" onclick=""NewWindow\('([^']*)',\s*'([^']*)',.*");`

I am getting no result, match.Succes is not true and if I output it in a textbox I get no text (Couldnt find it).

Comment: You need 2 quotes to mean one literal quote. Use 4 quotes to mean 2 literal quotes. So... `class=""""` instead.

Comment: OK, I see. Just change your pattern to `@"class="""" onclick=...` - you need to escape double qoutes

Comment: @user2911924 You're welcome! But consider accepting an answer from your previous question by clicking on the tick outline on the left side of the answer :)

Comment: @Jerry alright! Why do people downvote my questions? Is it like to easy? Just a little new to it :S

Comment: @user2911924 don't know why your first question was downvoted (looks OK to me), but you can just remove this one, because it is already answered in comments and your downvotes will be gone